# What's the purpose of ThreadLocal here?

Tags: java, concurrency, thread-local

```
public class VPattern implements Pattern
{
    private final TokenKey tokenKey_;
    private final String tokenLabel_;
    private Integer cachedHashCode_ = null;
    private ThreadLocal<Token> token_ = new ThreadLocal<Token>();

    ...
}
```

I am reading this piece of code and don't understand the use of ThreadLocal here. Is that because ThreadLocal is used to ensure the 'token_' object will be thread safe in any concurrent situation? If that's the case, why TokenKey and Integer are not thread safety protected? I know that "String" is always thread safe.

Answer (score 2):

Every thread gets its own `Token` even if they share the same instance of `VPattern`. Possibly this was done because `Token` is not thread safe and `VPattern` wants to avoid synchronizing access to the `Token` instance. `tokenKey_` is final so don't have to worry about the field changing, and maybe it's thread safe on its own. `tokenLabel_` is also final and strings are immutable so no issue there. `cachedHashCode_` is the odd one out here; is access to it protected somehow? It's hard to say what's going on without seeing the rest of the class.

Comment: Hi, Wills, tokenKey is safe because it is final? And secondly, so generally, when I want to ensure the thread safety of an instance variable, I can use ThreadLocal to protect it. Is that a good practice, right?

Comment: If 'final' can ensure thread safety, why isn't 'final' used for the Token variable, but a ThreadLocal is used?

Comment: Making the fields `final` helps make `VPattern` thread safe because it doesn't have to worry about one thread writing to the field while another is trying to read it. The field is set once in the constructor (when there can only be one thread) and is never written again.

Comment: The thread safety of the field *value* is separate. `String` and `Integer` are immutable objects and are thread safe. I don't know about `Token` but maybe not. If it's not thread safe, or would be expensive to make thread safe, then that's possibly why this code gives each thread its own `Token` instance. (It's just a guess. There might be some other reason; maybe the program just wants each thread to have its own `Token` for identification purposes, who knows.)

Comment: I am surprised that the `token_` field is not `final`. It seems like it could be. I doubt the program ever replaces the `ThreadLocal` with a new one.

Comment: `cachedHashCode_` is not `final` because its purpose is to (as the name suggests) cache the hash code of `VPattern`, which possibly is expensive to calculate. But if it's expensive to calculate, we don't want to do it if we don't have to. So the class initializes it to `null`, but if someone actually calls `hashCode`, then the class will calculate it the first time and store it in `cachedHashCode_`. I am wondering what the `hashCode` method looks like. Is it `synchronized`? The class may be sloppy since if multiple threads calculate the hash code, they'll all come up with the same value.

Comment: Would 'private final Token token_', without using ThreadLocal, make it thread safe?

Comment: It's hard to say for sure without seeing the code. (I mentioned this in my question too. It's a hint!) But in general, no, whether or not `Token` is thread safe has nothing to do with whether a field in another class that potentially references a `Token` is `final` or not. Making the `token_` field `final` helps with the thread safety of `VPattern`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203125/discussion-between-ling-and-willis-blackburn).

Answer (score 1):

In general, `ThreadLocal` can provide different objects for each working thread. So if the given object is not thread-safe nor singleton, it can be stored in `ThreadLocal` variable. Then every thread may get and safely use different instance of your class. You can treat it like a map, where the current thread is a key and the actual object is a value.

Let's assume there are two threads working at the same time and sharing one `VPattern` object. If threads get `tokenKey_` or `tokenLabel_`, then both will get the same instances. But if both threads call `token.get()`, then they will get different instances of `Token` type (if initialized previously, see: `set` method and `withInitial` static factory method).

Unfortunately it's hard to say what's the purpose of `ThreadLocal` in your case because it highly depends on the context. Seems that `Token` objects cannot be shared by different threads (each thread should have own token).

You can read more about `ThreadLocal` in javadoc or here: https://www.baeldung.com/java-threadlocal